# Div's don't show up

Tags: html, css

I have some divs that won't show up, no matter what I do.

The relevant divs have the class 'baumX', where X is the number of the div.

```
<div class='pachten'>                       
    <div class='pachtlogo'><img src='_img/zeigen.png'></div>
    <h1>some header</h1>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <div class='pachtimg'><!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
    <p>text again</p>
    <div class='baum 1'> <!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.pachten {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background-color: #FFC734 ;
}
.baum1 , .baum2 , .baum3 , .baum4 {
    min-width: 15%;
    min-heigth: 15%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.baum1 {
    border-left:4 px solid #fff;
    border-top:4 px solid #fff;
    float:right;
}
```

.pachtlogo and .pachtimg are empty so far, their css gets added later.

Even when I put some content into the div, the content shows but the div doesn't.

EDIT: Solved, simply a typo. Gonna delete the question when it's marked solved to give you guys some rep for showing me how stupid one can be.

Comment: <div class='baum 1'>  Why is there a space there?  That class does not exist.

Comment: maybe a typo? ´<div class='baum 1'>´ --> ´<div class='baum1'>´

Comment: that solved it, god i feel so stupid right now, thanks a lot, it works now

Comment: You don't have to delete this question, maybe someone later will have the same problem and will find his answer here instead of having to ask it himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so class baum1 and baum 1 are totally different! In your div you have `class="baum 1"` notice the space in between, That makes it so there are 2 classes. class `.baum` and class `.1`. 
Just remove the space in your div and your style sheet should see that is class `.baum1`.

```
<div class='pachten'>                       
<div class='pachtlogo'><img src='_img/zeigen.png'></div>
<h1>some header</h1>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<div class='pachtimg'><!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
<p>text again</p>
<div class='baum1'> <!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<div class='baum 1'> <!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
```

Should be this:

```
<div class='baum1'> <!-- Some img that gets added later --></div>
```

The space in your class name made it not match the one you defined in your CSS.